# How can I update text by linking a Button and a ComboBox in Tkinter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tk-toolkit

I need to link 4 buttons to a Label that has default text in it, and need to update the text in the Label based on the selected option in the combo box I have set up.

I've tried to create functions to link the two, but I'm not experienced with linking Combo Box and Label attributes together so it hasn't been working.

Comment: Please add a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so that we can offer relevant advice.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Next time search on the google... The answer is simple, all you need to do is to update the values... But if you want to delete values from the list you will need to update and the current index because combobox will not erase the selected value and is normal because overall combobox is build on top of entry class

I write and small example to test the workflow:

```py
#// IMPORT
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk


#// GLOBAL VAR's
AppTitle:str = "StackOverflow"
AppSize:tuple[int, int] = 512, 256


#// LOGIC
class App:
    def __init__(self, master:tk.Tk) -> None:
        self.master = master

        # Configure the window title
        self.master.title(AppTitle)
        # Configure the window size and position
        self.__ox = (self.master.winfo_screenwidth() - AppSize[0]) // 2
        self.__oy = (self.master.winfo_screenheight() - AppSize[1]) // 2
        self.master.geometry("{size[0]}x{size[1]}+{offsetX}+{offsetY}".format(
            size=AppSize, offsetX=self.__ox, offsetY=self.__oy))

        # Content - Frames
        self.FrameMain = tk.Frame(self.master)
        self.FrameDropDown = tk.Frame(self.FrameMain)
        self.FrameEntry = tk.Frame(self.FrameMain)
        self.FrameMain.pack(expand=True, fill="both")
        self.FrameDropDown.pack(expand=False, fill="x", side="top")
        self.FrameEntry.pack(expand=False, fill="x", side="bottom")

        # Content - New value
        self.Entry = ttk.Entry(self.FrameEntry)
        self.EntryBtnAdd = ttk.Button(self.FrameEntry, text="Add", width=10,
                                      command=lambda:self.__callback_new_value())
        self.Entry.pack(expand=True, fill="x",side="left")
        self.EntryBtnAdd.pack(expand=False, side="left")

        # Content - Remove value
        self.EntryBtnDel = ttk.Button(self.FrameDropDown, text="Remove", width=10,
                                      command=lambda:self.__callback_remove_value())
        self.EntryBtnDel.pack(expand=False, side="right")

        # Content - Text
        self.Text = ttk.Label(self.FrameMain, font=("Comic Sans MS", 24, "bold"))
        self.Text.pack(expand=False, fill="x", side="bottom", padx=5, pady=5)

        # Content - Combobox
        self.currentValue = tk.StringVar()
        self.dropDownMenu = ttk.Combobox(self.FrameDropDown, textvariable=self.currentValue, state="readonly")
        self.dropDownMenu.pack(expand=True, fill="x", side="left")
        # Provide some values and set a default one
        self.dropDownMenu["values"] = [f"Value {i+1}" for i in range(7)]
        self.dropDownMenu.current(2)

        # Linking Label and Combobox is happening here...
        self.dropDownMenu.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>", self.__callback_value_changed)

        # Update some stuffs just for my visual effect pleasure
        # In other words, I provide some default values here
        self.__callback_value_changed()
        self.Entry.insert(0, "Some new value here...")

    def __callback_value_changed(self, *argsNotUsed) -> None:
        """Just change the text with the "dropdown menu" value

        :param argsNotUsed: Values can be provided, but are not used.
        :returns:   Nothing."""
        self.Text.configure(text=self.dropDownMenu.get())

    def __callback_new_value(self) -> None:
        """Just add some new values to the "dropdown menu"

        :returns:   Nothing."""
        values:tuple[str] = self.dropDownMenu["values"]
        newValue:str = self.Entry.get()

        # Add new value just if not exist yet
        if newValue not in values:
            self.dropDownMenu["values"] = [*values, newValue]

    def __callback_remove_value(self) -> None:
        """Just remove some values from the "dropdown menu"

        :returns:   Nothing."""
        values:list[str] = list(self.dropDownMenu["values"])
        value:str = self.dropDownMenu.get()
        index:int = values.index(value)

        # Remove the value from the list and update the new values list
        values.remove(value)
        self.dropDownMenu["values"] = values
        # Just for visual purpose, update the selected item by setting the value before what was deleted
        self.dropDownMenu.current(max(0, index - 1))
        # Also, for the seek of visual case, trigger the callback for the value changed
        # (in other words: change the text to)
        self.__callback_value_changed()


#// RUN (just if this is the main file opened)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()
    app = App(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

Test it on Windows 10:

[image: preview]